# why is group by giving this not an aggregated function error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have used **AdventureworksLT2008R2** for this query, the query is

```
select p.Color, SUM(p.ListPrice) as total, pc.Name from SalesLT.Product p 
inner join SalesLT.ProductCategory pc on p.ProductCategoryID=pc.ProductCategoryID
group by p.Color
go
```

purpose is to sumup list prices of each product grouped by color e.g.

it should display like

**------+-----------+---------
color |  ListPrice | Name
------+-----------+---------
red   | 100000    | Bike
Black |  12000    |  Clothing
------------------------------**

but instead it gives this error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'SalesLT.ProductCategory.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

if i do thsi without inner join i.e not having Name column

```
select p.Color, SUM(p.ListPrice) as total from SalesLT.Product p 
group by p.Color
```

the code works but it failed with the inner join

Why this error occurs even i see nothing wrong with the logic? and how do i fix this?

thanks

Comment: Because it isn't part of the group by...exactly as the error message states.

Comment: ... It isn't part of the group by column list, or inside an aggregate expression.

Comment: i should remove Color from group by and add ListPrice, but then it cannot display by colors

Comment: @AndrewMC change your group by to `group by p.Color, pc.Name`  All columns in the select list need to exist in an aggregate function or a group by when aggregating data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> select p.Color, SUM(p.ListPrice) as total, pc.Name
>   group by p.Color

You need to add pc.Name to the GROUP BY statement, as GROUP BY has to have all columns in the SELECT clause that are not part of an aggregate like SUM, COUNT, etc.